# Checking if CELL in excel is blank before populating with Form answer

Tags: excel, if-statement, expression, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I am trying to write an expression that will check if a cell in a row in excel is blank, and if it is then insert an answer from a microsoft form, but if it isn't blank then just leave it as is.

For a bit of background info, The flow I am writing does the following:

Takes a response from a microsoft form - which users fill out when they are changing job role - and then fills in the appropriate cells according to whats required for that job.

I have over 90 columns in my table and each job role (10 approx.) requires a different combination of each, so it was very time consuming to go in and insert the form response into each required column - see below.

[image: Update a row action]

So I am trying to write an expression that will check the contents of the cell  to prevent overwriting already existing information.

I tried something like the following:

```
if(outputs('Get_a_row')?['body/HR PO 004'] = "","R"outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r4cbf6e58f25742ff8104f08b6afe1b5e'],)
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s all expression based in PowerAutomate, much like Excel, try this instead (***untested***) ...

```
if(equals(body('Get_a_row')?['HR PO 004'], ''), body('Get_response_details')?['r4cbf6e58f25742ff8104f08b6afe1b5e'], body('Get_a_row')?['HR PO 004'])
```

... also, you've noticed I've changed out `outputs` for `body`.

If it doesn't work 100%, you'll at least understand that you need to use the `equals` function to perform the comparison, not an operator like `=`.

Comment: If I wanted to put a letter R before the date that gets inserted during 'get_response_details', how would I format this?

Comment: Ahhhh yes, I overlooked that. Look at using the concat function … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#concat